# Loading dynamic link in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `iframe` that I want to load the id from a variable. The issue is structuring the link so that it works. If I hardcode the actual number its fine, but if I add the variable to the end, it comes back as undefined. Any help would be great.

```js
$(document).ready(){
var path='https://url.com?ou='+youvariable;
var youvariable=6606;
console.log(path);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<iframe src="" width="600px" height="400px"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the variable before intialization, that's why it returns `undefined`.

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var youvariable=6606;
   var path='https://url.com?ou='+youvariable;
   console.log(path);
})
```

just declare the variable before using it.

Comment: ok could it be outside of the initialization?

Comment: @Vzupo what do you mean?

Comment: what if i had a variable not in jquery but vanilla javascript that I wanted to use?

Comment: firstly, jQuery is just a library of JavaScript, so it just an way to make things easier. secondly variable declaration rules stay the same if you use jQuery, ES, React or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your `document.ready()` needs a function as an argument, like...

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  //your code here
});
```

secondly, the variable needs to be declared before it is used.

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  var youvariable=6606;
  var path='https://url.com?ou='+youvariable;
  console.log(path);
});
```

Output:

```
"https://url.com?ou=6606"
```